# How to convert a Python 'bytes' object to ctypes 'POINTER(c_byte)'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I want to write a ctypes wrapper for a C function with this signature:

```
int utp_process_udp(utp_context *ctx, const byte *buf, size_t len, const struct sockaddr *to, socklen_t tolen);
```

And to have some type checking I've added this to my Python wrapper:

```
libutp.utp_process_udp.argtypes = [POINTER(UtpContext), POINTER(c_byte), c_size_t, POINTER(sockaddr_in), c_int]
```

But when I pass a `bytes` object as the `buf` argument I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ucat.py", line 269, in <module>
    main()
  File "ucat.py", line 251, in main
    network_loop()
  File "ucat.py", line 138, in network_loop
    utp.utp_process_udp(ctx, data, addr)
  File "/home/mostafa/source/pyutp/utp.py", line 159, in utp_process_udp
    POINTER(c_byte)(data), c_size_t(len(data)),
TypeError: expected c_byte instead of bytes
```

If I don't set `argtypes` I can successfully call the function though, so obviously the `bytes` object *can* be passed to this function. Is there anything I should do to let ctypes know what I'm doing? Some sort of cast perhaps? (I *have* tried using the `ctypes.cast` function but that did not work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used `POINTER(c_char)` instead of `POINTER(c_byte)` and the problem went away.

Comment: You can use `c_char_p` instead. Note that in this case it's ok to pass an immutable `bytes` object because the parameter type is qualified as a `const byte` pointer.

Comment: @eryksun The docs explicitly say that `c_char_p` is for NULL-terminated strings and this is obviously not one of those here.

Comment: As a result type that would matter, since the getfunc would try to create a string automatically, looking for a null terminator where perhaps none exists. That could segfault, so yes, that's an important distinction for a result type.  As a parameter type it does not matter one bit. All the C function sees is a pointer to the first byte of the string.

Comment: BTW, CPython `bytes` and `str` types are implemented as null-terminated strings. `c_char_p.from_param` passes the object's internal pointer. That's why you have to be careful to only pass `bytes` and `str` for parameters that are marked as `const`. Otherwise you could end up violating CPython's expectation that immutable objects can be interned.

Comment: Also note that `POINTER` uses a type cache and `POINTER(c_char)` is already defined and special cased to use the `from_param` converter method from `c_char_p`, i.e. the line `POINTER(c_char).from_param = c_char_p.from_param` in the `_reset_cache` function.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use: **ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte)**